# Voltage surge suppression technique in high-speed switching based electronic circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, switches, passive-networks, circuit-protection, surge-protection

I am working on a circuit that transmits ~1MHz sine wave(20V amplitude) in RLC based circuit scheme, also transmits high-frequency signals(pulses(non-periodic)) ~20MHz(10 %DS)(20V) in a CR-based circuit scheme. The circuit involves 'disabling' of inductor for ~20MHz signal transmission for a short amount of time(say 10% of the enabled time).
I'm having problems in suppressing the voltage spikes(~ +-100 V) which are generated the moment I disable the inductor AND after I connect the wire, while the rest of the time the circuit behaves alright. NOTE: I'm measuring the differential voltage across Resistor(275ohm)
[image: circuit]

XFG3: 20MHZ, 10%DS +- 20V square wave

XFG2: 1.58MHz(RLC resonant), 50%DS, +- 20V square wave

XFG4,1: 500KHz, 10%DS

Desired output: Maximum power transfer at 275ohms(after rectification, filter) + High-speed data transmission(to be demodulated later from 275ohms)

So, to tackle that, I came up with an idea to temporarily enable the pair of opposite Zener diodes which would act as a voltage limiter(say +-20V) right after the switch S1, but it found to be unsuccessful. I can still see the surges. Also, I've read that Zener has high capacitance, so it won't be effective in a high speed temporarily switching(Note that I want to enable the voltage suppression device momentarily for the initial surge protection(~10ns))
[image: with zener]
[image: surges]

I also have an idea to make my switch kind of a hybrid-relay based, where there will be a state for a very short period of time (just after inductor open-circuit and before connecting the wire) to absorb the surges. But, I'm not getting effective ideas.

I also have heard about MOVs. But I'm not sure about its effectiveness as they also possess capacitance. It's not available in NI Multisim, so I am not sure if it's good.

I need some suggestions/ways to tackle the problem.
NOTE: C1 capacitor is an instrument that is very delicate and it's a must to suppress any kind of spike just before it

Comment: Surely the voltage spike suppressor would be right *before* S1, on the left side?

Comment: also can you explain why you have this circuit? Maybe there is a better way to do whatever you're doing

Comment: Be it on the left of S1 or on the right, the effect would be the same, isn't it? However I've tried every possibility with the Zener pair, it doesn't work well. I'm using the circuit for power(low freq)+data(high freq) in an application. So, right now, the modulation scheme is fixed here

Comment: I don't see any circuit that is shorting the inductor.

Comment: @deadplasma Well if you put your spike suppressor on the right of S1 then when you disconnect the inductor, it's not connected to the spike suppressor any more, so how could it suppress the spike?

Comment: @Andyaka, my bad. I'll change the 'shorting' to 'disabling' the inductor.

Comment: @user253751 please check the edits I've made to the question. However, You're correct, but I need to protect surges before C1 at any cost. That's why I need to ensure a suppressor just before it. However, we can have multiple suppressors, that's not an issue

Comment: Suppression must be done before the switch but can you define XFG1,2,3,4 better? and desired output

Comment: you mean something like this ? https://tinyurl.com/ycqoe2u8

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I can have access to only 275ohms R. Output is taken differentially across R. And the Zener pair I used were connected right after 100ohm and gnd. I was temporarily enabling them with 500KHz, 1%DS to suppress the spike.

Comment: Change my simulation to match and export shortcut. The voltage is shown across 275

Comment: But I have no idea what you expect this to do.

Comment: https://tinyurl.com/y9gh982n . @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Is the Zener configuration improper according to the circuit image I posted? Can you tell me about any other idea? What about MOV?

Comment: Yes S1-2 will have a huge spike. What do are you really trying to accomplish?  The voltage across inductor will swing as high as you let it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this configuration:
When S1 is bypassing L1, SW3 is closed.
When S1 is in series with L1, SW3 is open.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frbaVu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
It should quickly quelch any energy in the inductor, and keep it local to that loop.

Comment: I tried it, but it isn't effective !!